# Changing hard coded variable value to user input in Python script with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, modelbuilder, python-script-tool

I have exported "Con Tool" script from ModelBuilder. The model has two input parameters one is the DEM and the second is "Long Variable". When I run the model it executes perfectly fine but as I import the script to tool box and assign the variables and type and run them the Python log shows errors.
I believe the script is taking the variable name instead of its value.

How do I fix that?

This is the script:

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# conmodelscript.py
# Created on: 2020-07-24 11:51:39.00000
#   (generated by ArcGIS/ModelBuilder)
# Usage: conmodelscript <DEM> <Input_Value> 
# Description: 
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Script arguments
DEM = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

Input_Value = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

# Local variables:
Long = "1"
Output = "C:\\Users\\92347\\Desktop\\test\\output.tif"

# Process: Con
arcpy.gp.Con_sa(DEM, Long, Output, "", "Value<=%Input Value%")
```

This is the model

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is how I add and run the script

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain the error message as text, so that is searchable by others.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has inherited the ModelBuilder inline substitution syntax, which you need to fix to make the code work.

Change this line:

```
arcpy.gp.Con_sa(DEM, Long, Output, "", "Value<=%Input Value%")
```

to:

```
arcpy.gp.Con_sa(DEM, Long, Output, "", "Value <= " + Input_Value)
```

As you set the variable `Input_Value` using GetParameterAsText() it is converting the number into a string so a simple concatenation is all that is required for the where clause in Con().

Comment: Thank you so so much. You're a life savior <3 God Bless

Comment: @MudassarShah If this has answered your question please consider up-voting and marking as the answer.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](//gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)